# Check if registry key + value exists and if so, log it

Tags: batch-file

I want to check if a certain registry key exists and if so, check its value as well

if it equals 0 (for example), then write to log: not found
if it equals 1 (for example), then write to log: found

should I stick to reg query and if structure or is there an easier method?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I check if a key is present in the windows registry

This can be done using `reg query key`:

- This command will set `%errorlevel%`.
- `errorlevel=0` means the key exists.
- `errorlevel=1` means the key does not exist.

---

#### Example batch file

```
@echo off
Set mykey="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"^
^ "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"^
^ "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"^
^ "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices"^
^ "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices"^
^ "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options"^
^ "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"^
^ "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Hackoo"

Set LogFile=logkey.txt
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%

For %%K in (%mykey%) Do Call :Check_Key %%K %LogFile%
Start "" %LogFile%
Exit /b

:Check_Key
reg QUERY %1 >nul 2>&1
(
    if %errorlevel% equ 0 ( echo %1 ===^> Found && reg QUERY %1 
        ) else ( echo %1 ===^> Not found 
    )
) >>%2 2>&1
```

---

#### Further reading

- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't found a proper way to check if the value is actually correct. You can use a FOR loop and tokens= to locate the value and compare but what happens when the REG QUERY returns more tokens than you're expecting? Using FIND fails in both a simple REG QUERY | FIND and in the FOR loop because it always returns the wrong %ERRORLEVEL% beyond one level. Even with DelayedExpansion, it seems it will eventually fail.